# How can I update a property of a list value based on a map using streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have list of and a map. I need to match the value of list in the map and replace the list value with the map value.
Basically I need to replace my `error_msg` from `Reponses` with the value present in `errormapping`.

```java
private Map<String, String> errormapping;

private List<Reponses> reponse;

public class Reponses{
    private String id;
    private String error_msg;
}

reponse.stream().forEach(e->e.getError_msg())
```

Kind of stuck here

Answer (score 1):

Use the key to get the value from the map and set the value:

```
reponses.stream().forEach(r -> r.setError_msg(errorMapping.get(r.getError_msg())));
```

This does not take into account the possibility, that the key does not exist in the map(your question does not specify, if that's possible scenario).

Additionally using stream for this is an overkill, simple loop would do the job and is probably more readable.